# lein test with-profile unable to override test profile's env value

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojure.test

I am doing some Clojure pet project. I have some profiles like the following

```
{:test   {:env {:database-name     "library_test",
                :host-name         "192.168.33.10"
                :username          "library_admin"
                :password          ""
                :dbtype            "postgres"
                :driver-class-name "org.postgresql.Driver"}},
 :dev    {:env {:database-name     "library",
                :host-name         "192.168.33.10"
                :username          "library_admin"
                :password          ""
                :dbtype            "postgres"
                :driver-class-name "org.postgresql.Driver"}},
 :travis {:env {:database-name     "test_library_test",
                :host-name         "localhost"
                :username          "test_user"
                :password          "password"
                :dbtype            "postgres"
                :driver-class-name "org.postgresql.Driver"}}}
```

Now I am trying to setup Travis-CI for the project. I want to override the value of **test** profile CI while running test, for that I am using the following command

> lein with-profile travis test

Here lein is activating the **travis** profile but it's picking up the environment variables value from **test** profile instead of **travis** profile.

Did anyone face such issues?

Answer (score 1):

Why: Lein [merges `test` profile](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/test.clj#L225) by default. You can see the effective project map with `lein with-profile travis,test pprint`

Solution: I assume you're using `environ` or something like that. If so, you can export values with [env](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) in `UPCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORE` (e.g. `DATABASE_NAME=test_library_test`) and they will override values in profiles